# Есть ли для модуль sqlite для python под symbian?

Tags: python, symbian, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Написал скрипт который хронит некоторые данные в бд (sqlite). Скрипт написан на питоне. Хотелось бы использоваеть его на телефоне (Nokia c6-00 symbian 9.4). Поставил интерпритатор, но тут возникла проблемма. В комплекте с интерпритатором не идет модуль для работы с sqlite и не могу найти где скачать такой. М.б. кто то сталкивался с такой проблеммой? Нужен именно sqlite.

Comment: На одном из форумов нашел информацию что python последняя версия для symbian не поддерживает sqlite, хотя это не точно. Нашел альтернативу: e32db. Пример работы с python+symbian+e32db можно посмотреть тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/77761/

Comment: Ошибся e32db это библиотека для работы с разными бд в том числе с sqlite